# Sum formula is doing concatenation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have got excel which has forumula `=AVERAGE(Y1:Z1)` and gives me the value 4. I want to sum this number with 5 and get the result 9 so I tried two approaches `=AVERAGE(Y1:Z1) + 5` and `=Sum(AVERAGE(Y1:Z1) , 5)` but it gives the result 54 not 9 . So somehow its concatenating not adding.  I tried `=NUMBERVALUE(AVERAGE(Y1:Z1)) + 5 also but result is still 54` not sure what I am missing here

Edit :
I have got the answer both Y1 and Z1 are percentages format so once I change it to `=AVERAGE(Y1:Z1) + 5%` i get expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try putting 5 in a different cell, say x1, and then use the formula

`=AVERAGE(Y1:Z1)+$x$1`

Or you could also put the average in another cell, say x1, and use

`=$x$1+5`